# Discord.py | not enough values to unpack

Tags: python, json, discord

```
 with open("warns.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        user_data = data[str(a)]
        await ctx.send(f"Total warnings: {len(user_data)}")
        for mod , reason, time, warn_id, warns in user_data:
            warn_id_ = warn_id
            mod_ = mod
            reason_ = reason
            time_ = time
            warns_ = warns
        await ctx.send(f"ID: {warn_id_}, mod: {mod_}, reason: {reason_}, time: {time_}, warns: {warns_}")´´´
```

This is My Code.. I try to get following Values out of my warns.json!

warn_id mod reason time warns

Here is my Json:

```
{
"836495228629417984": {
    "mod": [
        763339711988236328
    ],
    "reason": [
        "test"
    ],
    "time": [
        "Friday, October 08 2021 @ 23:15:31 PM"
    ],
    "warn_id": [
        83299
    ],
    "warns": 1
}
```

But it returns :

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 3)
```

I dont Know how to fix that :/

Comment: You get 3 things when you want 5 things. To debug, you could replace the for loop with `for data in user_data: print(repr(data))`.

Comment: i only get the key names not the value inside the keys :/

Answer (score 0):

First of all your example json is not correct, it is missing one } at last.
Now your unpacking program may be like:

```
with open("warns.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for k in data:
        unpacked = data[k]
        warn_id_ = unpacked['warn_id']
        mod_ = unpacked['mod']
        reason_ = unpacked['reason']
        time_ = unpacked['time']
        warns_ = unpacked['warns']
```

Note - this minimal change is just to make your program working. But there may be other better solutions.

Comment: i know but it was stackoverflow fault with the missing "}" i gonna try this now!

Comment: thanks ! It worked :) you saved me haha